# req.param typeerror object has no method "param" shown?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running the below code, which runs fine on the first time but when I call the method second time it throws req.param typeerror object has no method "param" :

```
someTypeFn: function(req, callback){
    var Users = mongoose.model('someUsers');
    var self = this;
    console.log("req.param('email_id')" +req.param('email_id'));
    Users.find({email: req.param('email_id')}, function(err, data){
        if(data.length == 0){
            var data = {
                email: req.param('email_id'),
                isAdmin: false,
                type: ["type2"]
            };
            var user = new self(data);
            user.save(function(err, data){
                callback();
            });
        }else{
            if(data[0].type.indexOf("type2") < 0){
                self.update({email: req.param('email_id')},
                    { $push: {type: "type2"}},
                    function(err, dd){
                        callback();
                    });
            }else{
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The console shows the req.param value on the first time but on second time it throws error, Can any one suggest why its happening?
Thanks

Comment: Where  is the second console.log?

Comment: The same console, I am calling someTypeFn method twice from file.

Comment: how do you call `someTypeFn`? maybe an example

Comment: add the code snippet where you are calling the someTypeFn() along with the parameters.

Comment: Sorry guys found the fix.
I was sending req.param as a parameter when was calling it the second time from another function   Users. someTypeFn(req.param('email_id'), function(){});
That is why it was throwing the error.